# Creating JSON data to write to sqlite3 database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sqlite, yui

I have JavaScript code that creates some random values for voltage and amperage and then inputs that into a table in HTML format. What I want to do is take these random values that I create and somehow store them back into a metering data table that I have in my sqlite3 database. I believe I have to store these random values into a JSON object then through the use of YUI or jQuery send it back to the database. I am very confused as to what is going on and how I am supposed to interact with all the programs and different types of code I have going. Please ask questions and I will answer as best I can to help you help me.

My JS code that creates random variables works perfectly and puts those values into a table flawlessly. The code is as follows:

```
function savevalues(form) 
{
    var currentdatetime = new Date();
    dtold = currentdatetime.getTime();
    alert(dtold);

    var dur = form.durbox.value * 60;
    var reason = get_radio_value();
    var jT = 0;
    var jkWh = 0;       

    document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">')
    document.write('<tr>')
    document.write('<th>Timestamp</th>')
    document.write('<th>V</th>')
    document.write('<th>A</th>')
    document.write('<th>kW</th>')
    document.write('<th>kWh</th>')
    document.write('<th>Session ID</th>')

    for(i = dur; i >= 0; i -= 15)
    {   
        var jV = randomVoltage(23800,24200);
        var jA = randomAmperage(190,210);
        var jkW = Math.floor((jV * jA))/1000;
        jkWh = Math.floor(jkWh*10)/10;
        dtcurr = currentdatetime.getTime() + jT*60000;
        dt = (dtcurr - dtold)/60000;        
        document.write('<tr>')
        document.write('<td>' + (dt) + ' minutes</td>')
        document.write('<td>' + jV + ' V</td>')
        document.write('<td>' + jA + ' A</td>')
        document.write('<td>' + jkW + ' kW</td>')
        document.write('<td>' + jkWh + ' kWh</td>')
        document.write('<td>1</td>')
        document.write('</tr>')
        jT += 15;
        jkWh += 4.8;  
    }

    document.write('</table>') 
}
```

This will create simulated data every 15 minutes for the duration based on the user input of 'dur'

How do I get this data back to a sqlite3 db and stored?

Comment: My impression is that this depends on what your server supports for connecting to Sqlite3.

Comment: I see some funky HTML generation: what does this have to do with JSON or SQLite? Consider removing all this spurious code and concentrating on an actual issue - there are at least two tasks, although they can be further broken down. 1) How to *get* the data into JSON and *send* it somewhere useful; and 2) How to *store* this data in SQLite - *where* is this SQLite database anyway?

Comment: Your comment helped me weed a little further into my problem. Step 1 is what I am working on now. I will post another question as I am using YUI to iterate through a table to store the generated data into a JSON object. Once I store this information into a JSON object I need to send it back to the server. The database resides on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some sort of Server side language running on your server that you can POST the data back to.  You can then use jQuery's `$.post()` function to post the data and process it server side.